# mining pcie 16x and 1x together caused rejects

Tags: altcoin, cgminer, miner-configuration, gpu-mining, mining-setup

I have 5 msi radeon R9 290 cards and this board https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z87PLUS/specifications/ . With 3 pcie 16x everything runs smooth but, as soon as I add the first 1x into the equation, I start getting tons of rejects.
How do you run the two technologies concurrently.
I am running Win8.